# How to use Firebase-tools on Windows?

Tags: windows, npm, firebase, firebase-tools

I want to get started with firebase on a Windows machine but I don't understand the getting started instructions on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html.

I created a .html file with the following content (copied from the instruction on that page). That works, info is added to the database and retrieved from the database. However I'm lost on Linux like instructions like $ npm install -g firebase-tools on that page.

I installed nodejs following the link to nodejs.org on https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/quickstart.html

If I execute the above command (without the linux $-prompt) in the node.js screen I get the following error message npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell.
(Press Control-D to exit.)

So then what?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://torrid-inferno-6000.firebaseio.com/");
        myFirebaseRef.set({
            title: "Hello!",
            author: "Firebase",
            location: {
                city: "San Francisco",
                state: "California",
                zip: 94103
            }
        });
        myFirebaseRef.child("location/city").on("value", function(snapshot) {
            alert(snapshot.val());  // Alerts "San Francisco"
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically i had to open command prompt and switch to C:\Program Files\nodejs, where file npm is located), then npm commands can be executed according to instructions. Later on when firebase is installed perform a restart for the changes to PATH environment variable to take effect. After that the firebase (init, deploy, ...) command can be used to deploy a site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saved a lot of time for this detail.

Answer (score 1):

[Firepit](https://github.com/abehaskins/firepit) is a new CLI tool built for Windows that attempts to be the native firebase-tools

> Firepit is a standalone, portable version of the Firebase CLI which has no depedencies (including Node.js). Download, click, and immediately get access to both firebase and npm commands.

Worth checking out https://github.com/abehaskins/firepit