# Firebase Hosting set up issue

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm just trying to do a simple set-up for hosting on firebase. I'm following the instructions at (https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) but I'm missing something because I keep getting an error of:

'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."

What I've done:

1. Installed nodejs.
2. Set PATH = to C:\Program Files\nodejs; via control Panel
3. in cmd: `cd C:\Program Files\nodejs`
4. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
5. changed directory to folder with my html files
6. tried running both `firebase app init` and `firebase init` neither of which work and give me the same error

[image: screenshot of cmd]

Comment: See if this helps: [How to use Firebase-tools on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767685/how-to-use-firebase-tools-on-windows) Basically, the answer was to restart after updating the path.

Comment: Seamus, yes I saw that post already. I did restart the computer but it didn't help.

Comment: I think it might be an issue with the fact that I'm on Windows. But I still can't figure out how to get around it

Comment: From the root of `C:` try `dir /s firebase.exe`. It should find it. Add that directory to your `%PATH%`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Cross-post: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/46

Comment: can you tell me how can you solve this issue?

Answer (score 21):

I had this exact same error. I fixed it by changing the path variable to include firebase.

Try finding firebase.cmd on Windows through C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm. I couldn't find firebase.exe, which is where I got confused. Looking at your screenshot, I can see where the path is saved.

Just search for the firebase.cmd and add it to your %PATH%  `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Then restart and try again: firebase should be a valid command

Sorry this is a year late and hope this helps someone.

Comment: how do I add something to my %PATH%?

Comment: @J.Ko   Control panel  >> type 'env' in search   >> Edit Environment variables for your account >> Path >> Add your path

Comment: from where I find firebase,cmd?

Comment: AppData is not a file in my user directory?

Comment: AppData is a hidden directory inside the C:\Users\<yourusername>\ folder. 

Change the folder settings to show the hidden items and then once you have that complete path, 

open the cmd as administrator and type

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\npm

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to run

```
npm install -g firebase-tools .
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Script Kitty's answer, for windows solution only:

You are probably missing npm in your path. You can check it by `echo %PATH%` to make sure. Thus, open Environmental variables > system variables > path

see if you could not find `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm` there.

if not, add it following this [link](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html). Or simply add your npm path there.

Answer (score 1):

All of the Simple and Quick solution is here...

step1: just go to C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\npm
step2: copy the path of this "npm"-folder
step3: now go to start and type "env" and select first-option then
step4: now paste that path in "paths"-option by clicking on "edit"-button
step5: then click on "ok"  and restart your pc

Answer (score 0):

**open a terminal or cmd run as administrator mode**

or

**If you are using MS Windows:**

Open Start Menu or press Win button on your keyboard.

Type "variables".

Click on "Edit the system environment variables"

Click on "Environment Variables..." button.

In the "System variables" list select "Path" and click on the "Edit..." button under the list.
In the "Edit environment variable" dialog click on the "Browse..." button.

Navigate to the "c:\users\AppData\Roaming" dir and select the "npm" sub-dir, then click "OK".

In the "Edit environment variable" dialog click "OK".

In the "Environment Variables" dialog click on "OK".

**For the Linux users:**

Navigate to the home_dir.

Edit the hidden ".bash_profile" file.

Add line with following text "export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin".