# -bash: firebase: command not found

Tags: command-line, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I need to host website to google firebase hosting.
I looked almost everywhere but steel have the problem.
I have installed **npm install --global firebase** also **npm install -g firebase-tools** but when I want to use firebase command it says : "command not found"

[firebase-tools "-bash: firebase: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found)

[Firebase Hosting set up issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531235/firebase-hosting-set-up-issue)

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/46

this posts didn't helped

[image]

this is after **sudo npm install --global firebase-tools**

[image]

Comment: Installing NPM modules globally with sudo can lead to weird behaviour. If I were experiencing your problem, that's the first thing I'd look into. There is a guide [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md).

Answer (score 20):

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue though... what does it do? and what do you have to do next?

Comment: this sets the command firebase to execute the file at (whatever your npm binary prefix is)/bin/firebase

if this doesn't work, you have to `npm i -g firebase-tools` first

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to install Firebase Tools after a long time away from it on new computer... Use `npm i firebase --save` to set your project up and `npm install -g firebase-tools` to install the tools for e.g. serving your app locally, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS:

You can use this query

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```