# How to access installed firebase-tools in different steps in CircleCI

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, yaml, circleci, firebase-cli

In one of my projects experimenting **Circle CI** with **Firebase**. In order to use the `firebase` command for deployment purposes first the `firebase-tools` needs to be installed.

In my **config.yml** file the following stands - *simplified*:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@1.1.6
jobs:
  install-and-build:
    executor:
      name: node/default
    steps:
      - node/with-cache:
          steps:
            - checkout
            - run: npm install
            - run: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
            - run: npm run-script build
  deploy:
    executor:
      name: node/default
    steps:
      - node/with-cache:
          steps:
            - run: firebase --version
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - install-and-build:
          requires:
            - install-dependencies
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - install-and-build
```

**Issue:**

Once the `npm install -g firebase-tools` command is in different step then it does not recognize the `firebase` command lately and throws the following error:

> /bin/bash: firebase: command not found

I found a solution which eliminates the issue by moving the `firebase-tools` install step before usage as:

```
- node/with-cache:
    steps:
      - run: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
      - run: firebase --version
```

**Questions:**

I would say that solution is just a workaround instead of a proper one like moving the `firebase-tools` installation steps into the `install-and-build` one and using in the deployment step. I tried already the following ideas firstly based on my research:

1. Creating an `alias` as `` alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase" `` based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912491/bash-firebase-command-not-found).
2. Running `npm get prefix` to figure out which folder is containing the `firebase` command based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found).
3. Installing `firebase-tools` as a **devDependency** and using `save_cache` and `restore_cache` option to read from `node_modules` folder.

Probably the issue is something else what I don't see, none of them helped that much thus my questions:

1. Is there any solution which helps the pipeline accessing the `firebase` command after installed in any previous steps?
2. Is it fine to have the `firebase-tools` installation step in the deployment step? For some reason I don't like that.

Could someone enlighten me about this topic? Any idea is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want to install it in the same job where it's being used? The jobs are running in different containers, you shouldn't expect them to share state outside the workspace.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interesting, that explains why I cannot run once installed in different workspace. For some reason I wanted to do all the installation in one step and using the tool later but most probably that does not make to much sense in this term.

Comment: See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/concepts/#caches-workspaces-and-artifacts - you could persist it to the workspace, but it'd be much more straightforward to install as needed.

Comment: So the suggestion would be to go with the shared working solution, no need to separate the installation from the usage of `firebase-tools`. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get firebase tools up and running in my circleci. I used the following:

```
  # Install Firebase tools needed for firebase emulator
  - run:
      name: Install firebase tools
      command: |
        curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
  # Then start firebase emulator in the background
  - run:
      name: Start firebase emulator
      command: |
        firebase emulators:start --import=driver_app_data/export_directory
      background: true
```