# Why aren't the Firebase Commands Working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I aknowledge that this is a common issue, that has been discussed on stack overflow before. However, I have tried to implement the commands from other stack overflow questions and they have not worked.

These are the links I have used:

[firebase-tools "-bash: firebase: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found)

[-bash: firebase: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912491/bash-firebase-command-not-found)

It appeared that I had successfully installed firebase. However all tools used leads to this:

> command not found

I then implemented this:

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

Which did something strange to the terminal. But when I added commands to the new terminal, it still didn't work.

I also implemented the following:

```
npm get prefix
```

This returned:

> /Users/andrewt/.npm-global

The rest of the guide then said:

> And it should output something like /home/your-username/npm-global.

> Then in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (if you're in a Mac) file, add:

> export PATH="/home/your-username/npm-global/bin:$PATH" # Add npm bin PATH
> Note the "/bin" after the npm get prefix result.

But I have no idea what that means, and my attempts to implement it failed.

If you are able to break down how to fix the issue so that I can understand - it would be greatly appreciated. Particularly if you can explain how it is working.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the guide you are following? *update* never mind, see you mean one of the questions you linked.

Comment: Understanding how your system and shell works is “general computing” and a good thing to learn.

Comment: never heard of it before

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

These days, Firebase also providers a standalone/prebuilt binary version of the Firebase tools that is much easier to get started with, and provides the exact same functionality as the NPM module.

If you're only just getting started developing with NPM, I'd recommend using the standalone binary of the Firebase tools for your platform. Find the documentation and link for [Mac](https://firebase.tools/bin/macos/latest), [Windows](https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest), and [Linux](https://firebase.tools/bin/linux/latest) in the documentation on [installing the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli).