# 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. In windows command prompt

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

After installed Node.js and executing command in command prompt

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

so,this thing comes out

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\XPENDER\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\XPENDER\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase: node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\XPENDER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\XPENDER\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XPENDER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-21T18_08_50_912Z-debug.log
```

then executing `firebase login` results out

```
'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

so how login will be successful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Hosting set up issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531235/firebase-hosting-set-up-issue)

Comment: Also check [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/46) for dozens of possible fixes on this particular issue